# Reduce dataTable tr height

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am using dataTable jquery plugin.

I need to reduce the height of the rows, how can I do it? (I need a fixed height)

I tried:

```
.dataTables tbody tr {
    min-height: 35px; /* or whatever height you need to make them all consistent */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nz05kgs6/)

Comment: `TR` don't have height.

You'll have to apply the height to its `td`s. [Little fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/x9o891c5/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tr` don't have height.

You'll have to apply the `height` to its `td`s

[Click here to see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9o891c5/)

Comment: This works, but this does not set a fixed height. If the data is big then the row height increases automatically. How am I supposed to set a fixed height? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Change the td padding CSS like this:

```
table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody td {
        padding: 1px 1px; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS's `padding` will also do the trick - take a look at this [example](http://live.datatables.net/nufabavi/1/edit) here. This came from [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29116/row-height) forum discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your CSS:

```
<style>
    td {
        white-space: nowrap;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

These DataTable options will make it even better:

```
scrollY: "530px",
scrollX: true,
scrollCollapse: true,
```